Docker containers have intermittent internet connection issues
I'm currently running Selenium in Debian 12 docker containers. There are 5 servers: 1 manager and 4 workers using docker. Quite often the first set of selenium tests will fail because the container doesn't have internet access, so it can't connect to the test site. Some or all of the servers can have this issue at the same time, but they do not always/consistently have the issue based on any discernable pattern. They will also magically resolve the issue. There will also be times where one automated test run is having problems connecting and a separate test run is working fine. Network manager says there are no error messages on the two DNS servers.
This issue arose when I changed to Debian 12 from Centos 9. I have changed 1 server back to centos 9 and it's having the same issue. Running an automated test on this server, there will be containers in the same hub (2 hubs, 40 containers each) that will have internet connection issues and others work fine.
The error found in the server logs when it is happening:
msg="[resolver] failed to query external DNS server" client-addr="udp:172.18.x.xx:45568" dns-server="udp:10.yy.yy.yyy:53" error="read udp 172.18.x.xx:45568->10.yy.yy.yyy:53
/etc/resolve.conf file (verified not a link):
# Generated by NetworkManager
search company.domain
nameserver 10.yy.yy.yyy
nameserver 10.yy.yy.zzz

Things I've tried with no improvements:
Hardcoding DNS addresses in /etc/docker/daemon.json
Downgrading docker
Upgrading docker
Restarting docker
Restarting servers
I have been beating my head against this flaky issue for nearly a month and I haven't made any progress. Do y'all have any thoughts?
